# Calling non-action method from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I am new to MVC and I cannot find the solution for my problem. I would like to call non-action method (which return string, int etc) from another controller. Is it even possible? How to do it properly? I am using ninject and my controller looks like this:

```
public class ShopController : Controller
{
  private IShopRepository repository;

  public ShopController(IShopRepository shopRepository)
  {
    this.repository = shopRepository;
  }

  public int GetShopId(string shopName)
  {
    // how to call this method from another controller?
    // here is linq query which needs shop table repository!
  }
}
```

Sorry for my english and many thanks for your replies!:)

Comment: just declare this non-action method as static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having controllers call instance methods of other controllers isn't the best design. I suggest you add the method `GetShopId` to the `IShopRepository` instead so that every component using the repository has access to it (including your other controller). The `IShopRepository` is where this method belongs, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to inherit from the controller whose method you want to use (provided that the method is not private).